# How can I create a GitHub project for my organization without using a browser?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-api

How can I create a GitHub project for my organization without using a browser?

I need to use the command line.

Comment: Why do you have that tough restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both GitLab and GitHub offer API which can help you creating projects without using the browser. Though you need the browser only once to get the token. You can find more info about [GitLab here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project-for-user) and  [GitHub here](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/)